# What Apple iOS Developer user types can create new provisioning files?

Tags: ios, iphone

For iTunes we create technical users which manage all tasks regarding handling app from testing to publishing.

Can I create a similar user in Apple iOS Developer console which can access only provisioning part to create provisioning profiles, add devices, etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a team agent can work in the provisioning portal...

I had to use the team agent user of a client of mine when we released an app recently.

Normally I just use the team agent user anyway, or sit beside the team agent and guide him/her through each step.  But that recent client Didn't give me access to team agent (at first) but gave me a technical user, or admin, I cannot remember. But I requested the team agent after failing to access the provisioning portal.

The team agent is the only user authorized to do provisioning, *unless something in Apple policy or Xcode behavior has changed since the last time I looked it up*.

Comment: How do you create it in Developer console?

Comment: Docs say "If you are enrolled in the iOS Developer Program as a company and hold either the Agent or Admin role, you can invite co-workers to join your development team by visiting the People tab in Member Center.". Does this mean that only a company user can create users? Individual cannot?

Comment: That's right. I am registered as an individual, but have helpef other companies get registered. As a company registered, there are obviously other people who may need to manage various tasks, given their roles in the company. Test (fake itunes) users and other lower users, even financial users cannot invite or create new users. Admin-levrl jsers can do almost anything. But the act of creating provisioning profiles and app IDs and ESPECIALLY submitting apps, these are tasks reserved exclusively to the top-level account, the Team Agent. Any individual signed up is automatically a Team Agent.

Comment: So that's why I could not find users link :). Thanks Tom

Comment: I typed that message on my iPad. Sorry for the horrible typos.